Json Schema draft-07, make property required based on another property value
I know this question exists here, but I tried every solution, but didnt work.
I have schema which has two properties, and second property will be displayed when first property is true. For this I used "options/dependencies". I want to make second property required when first property is true.
    "authorizationNumber": {
      "type": "object",
      "format": "grid-strict",
      "required": ["firstProperty"],
      "properties": {
        "firstProperty": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "default": false,
          "options": {
            "grid_columns": 3
          }
        },
        "secondProperty": {
          "type": "array",
          "format": "select2",
          "uniqueItems": true,
          "minItems": 1,
          "items": {
            "type": "string",
            "$ref": "#/definitions/serviceCode"
          },
          "options": {
            "dependencies": {
              "firstProperty": true
            },
            "select2": {
              "closeOnSelect": true,
              "tags": false
            },
            "grid_columns": 4
          }
        }
      }
    }

I tried if/then/else as below:
    "authorizationNumber": {
      "type": "object",
      "format": "grid-strict",
      "required": ["firstProperty"],
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "authorizationNumberAvailable":{
            "const": true
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "required": ["secondProperty"]
      },
      "properties": {
        "firstProperty": {
        "type": "boolean",
        "default": false,
        "options": {
          "grid_columns": 3
        }
       },
      "secondProperty": {
        "type": "array",
        "format": "select2",
        "uniqueItems": true,
        "minItems": 1,
        "items": {
          "type": "string",
          "$ref": "#/definitions/serviceCode"
        },
        "options": {
          "dependencies": {
            "firstProperty": true
          },
          "select2": {
            "closeOnSelect": true,
            "tags": false
          },
          "grid_columns": 4
        }
      }
    }
  }

This does not give any errors, but it is not setting the "secondProperty" as required.
I also tried wrapping if/then with "allOf" as it is suggested one of the answers. To conclude, "secondProperty" should be available and marked as required when "firstProperty" is set to true.

Your if, then statement is at the wrong level.
Try this
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "authorizationNumber": {
      "type": "object",
      "format": "grid-strict",
      "required": [
        "firstProperty"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "firstProperty": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "default": false,
          "options": {
            "grid_columns": 3
          }
        },
        "secondProperty": {
          "type": "array",
          "uniqueItems": true,
          "minItems": 1,
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/serviceCode"
          },
          "options": {
            "dependencies": {
              "firstProperty": true
            },
            "select2": {
              "closeOnSelect": true,
              "tags": false
            },
            "grid_columns": 4
          }
        }
      },
      "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "firstProperty": {
                "const": true
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "required": [
              "secondProperty"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "serviceCode": {}
  }
}

